# Maintain duplicate record across databases

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have some data that I would like to keep consistent across two separate databases. This may seem ridiculous, but it's something we'd like to do for our project.

My initial thoughts were to use something like:

`@event.listens_for(Table, "after_insert")`

and then create a new session within this even to insert into the new database (and likewise for updates)

I don't believe the new session can use the ORM Table object, or it will just spin, as the event triggers repeatedly (so I can just use raw SQL). Is there a clean way of doing this with sqlalchemy? I experimented with [binds](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/binds/), but it seems like they are more for splitting data across databases (instead of duplicating)

**Update**

As @Tim mentioned, there probably isn't an easy way to do this in SQLAlchemy. The best solution is probably to pull it up into a layer above SQLAlchemy. Basically write functions like createMyModel(model, session1, session2)

Comment: I don't believe that there is an easy way to do this in SQLAlchemy.  I would personally suggest pulling it up into a layer above SQLAlchemy.  Basically write functions like `createMyModel(model, session1, session2)`.  These functions would write to both tables

Comment: Thanks, I hoping I could do something in SQLA, but I think that's the best solution. I'll close the question